# Placing html in static method in php class

Tags: php, html, class, templates

last year I start to using plain class and satic methods for generating html output in php. I'm very happy about it. However I'm a lonewolf developer which using non standart practices and now I found a new job in a development team.

sample class

```
<?php
class facade_front_footer extends ui
{
    public static function render($baseUri,$siteName,$info)
    {
        $_html = '
<footer class="text-center">
        <div class="footer-above">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3>Bizi takip edin</h3>
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3>'.$siteName.'</h3>
                        <p>'.$info.'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-below">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        Copyright Â© '.$siteName.' 2016
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
';

        return $_html;
    }
}
```

So I'm curious about is there any bad side effects for using classes for generating html output in php.

My humble regards.

Comment: A drawback might be you don't benefit from syntax highlighting, which lowers code readability, makes maintenance more difficult - may lead to difficult to track/debug errors.

Comment: Yes, some editörs or ide's have phtml support. I use similar methods for javasciprts which has worst syntax highlighting. 

However direct (ctrl+left mouse) access to template files was so good. 

I'm using component model for producting web pages. (lots of tiny plugins. render them first then collect in a layout)

So there is lots of components and lots of template files.

I did not found any other way to access template files so directly. This was my quick solution and I have no way to calculate side effects in long term